# Using a control gate on a classical wire in Qcircuit

Tags: floats, qcircuit

I would like to have a controlled gate operator on a classical wire, similar to Part F of Figure 3 in [Schuld 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10793.pdf).  When I try it in Qcircuit, it awkwardly uses a quantum wire on the left side control gate.

Minimal working example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[braket, qm]{qcircuit}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
$$ \label{circ:4train}
  \Qcircuit @C=.5em @R=0em @!R {
                        & & & & & &      &          &        &     &           &     &     & &  \\
  \ket{a_{0}} = \ket{0} & & & & & & \qw  & \gate{H} & \meter & \cw & \ctrlo{1} & \cw & \cw & &  \\
  \ket{m_{0}} = \ket{0} & & & & & & \qw  & \qw      & \qw    & \qw & \meter    & \cw & \cw & &  \\
  }
$$
\caption{Some circuit}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Which yields :

[image: control_gate_on_classical_wire]

When in reality, I want it to look like

[image]:

**Question** :

How do I keep the wire a classical wire (i.e. two lines) when using a controlled gate without Qcircuit defaulting to a single line (i.e. a quantum wire)?

Answer (score 4):

I did some digging and simply looked through the [Qcircuit stylesheet](https://github.com/CQuIC/qcircuit/blob/master/qcircuit.sty) and found that instead of using `ctrlo`, I should be using `\cctrlo`.  The full solution is here :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[braket, qm]{qcircuit}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\[ \label{circ:4train}
  \Qcircuit @C=.5em @R=0em @!R {
                        & & & & & &      &          &        &     &           &     &     & &  \\
  \ket{a_{0}} = \ket{0} & & & & & & \qw  & \gate{H} & \meter & \cw & \cctrlo{1} & \cw & \cw & &  \\
  \ket{m_{0}} = \ket{0} & & & & & & \qw  & \qw      & \qw    & \qw & \meter    & \cw & \cw & &  \\
  }
\]
\caption{Some circuit}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]